# Schedule a task to run before computer goes to hibernate

Tags: windows, hibernate, task-scheduler

I have a command script and I want to run it
before the computer goes to hibernate.

When I click on the hibernate option, then,
before going to hibernate, this task should work.

I have tried creating a basic task with trigger as below

- Type : On Event (Basic)
- Log : System
- Source : Kernel-Power
- EventID : 506

But it didn't trigger the task before hibernate.

I have checked the Windows Event Viewer;
it shows the event id for hibernate (506),
but Task Scheduler is not triggering the script to run.

[image]

Comment: Please include what your research has shown you so far, & why it wasn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: It's working now. My laptop was on battery not on AC adapter. And in task scheduler it was set that it should work only if ac adapter is connected thats why it was not working.

Comment: @User1991, the question is reasonable, and you comment could be somewhat expanded into an answer, which would be helpful to others. Specifically, you might explain use fo Modern Standby, rather than true (power off) Hibernate.